# How do I reformat a DataFrame efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column format something like this:

| ID | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1.0 |
| 001 | B | 2.0 |
| 001 | C | 3.0 |
| 002 | B | 1.5 |

How do I efficiently transform it into a format like this:

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
| 002 | N/A | 1.5 | N/A |

Essentially, I want to change the "type" column into its own set of columns, with the corresponding values attached. There are only three types present in the type column. Not every ID has values for all 3 types.

I've tried an approach where I iterate through every row of the dataframe using iterrows() and build a dictionary with format {ID:[], A:[], B:[], C:[]}, then converting that into another dataframe using from_dict(). This appears to work but seems slow and I am aware that iterating through individual rows of a dataframe is not recommended for speed.